# Same Size Buttons in Two LinearLayouts

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout

I have two `LinearLayout`s in my `Android` application. One (the top) holds a `TextView` and a `Button` and the one below it holds two `button`s. I was wondering if there was a way to make the right button of the upper `LinearLayout` the same size as the right button of the bottom `LinearLayout`.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal" android:paddingTop="15.0dip">

     <TextView 
          android:paddingLeft="5.0dip" 
          android:textSize="33px"
          android:textStyle="bold" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/textViewPoints" 
          android:text="Points: 0"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:paddingRight="25.0dip" 
          android:layout_weight="0" />

     <Button 
          android:enabled="false" 
          android:onClick="myClickHandler"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:id="@+id/buttonAddTracker"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:text="@string/buttonAddTracker" 
          android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingTop="15.0dip">

     <Button 
          android:text="Calculate" 
          android:id="@+id/button01"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1" 
          android:onClick="myClickHandler" />

     <Button 
          android:text="Reset" 
          android:id="@+id/button02"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button01" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="myClickHandler"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there are two ways how you can do that ...

1) If you are using Linear Layout as you are, then you'll have to fix the **WIDTH** of the **Left TextView and Left Button** then can't be wrap content , just give them say 40 dip . After that put **Right Buttons Width** to **fill_parent** or fix a WIDTH for them too .

2) Use TableLayout and put each of them in their respective columns and rows and the TableLayout should handle it for you.

Comment: Just to follow up with this, what I do now is WIDTH of 0dp and layout_weight of 1 for each button. Works perfectly, but thanks for help and sorry for late acceptance.